# Transition not triggering within event handler

Tags: javascript, css

Here is an example of what I want to achieve for the problem at hand:

https://codepen.io/binnny/pen/ExPpggQ

When I click the button, no `translateY()` is being triggered to slide down the `#main_card` so that `#next_card` appears. I also want to reset the transition, because each next card eventually becomes the main card, and new content has to be created for the next card.

So for each click it goes:

```
main: A --> next: B
main: B --> next: C
main: C -- next: D
```

What is actually happening is that the content is changing, but there is no slide down transitioning. Not sure how to remedy this to get the expected outcome for each click?

HTML

```
    <main id="quote-box">
      <div id="next_card">
        <p id="_text"></p>
        <p id="_author"></p>
      </div>
      <div id="main_card">
        <p id="text"></p>
        <p id="author"></p>
      </div>
    </main>
```

Sass

```
  #quote-box {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 80vw;
    height: 300px;
    margin: auto;
    border: 7px solid;

      #next_card {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-content: center;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        height: inherit;
      }

      #main_card {
        @extend #next_card;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
      }
    }
```

JavaScript

```
var quotes = [
  {text: "Hello Earth!", author: "Me"}, {text: "Hello Mars!", author: "You"}, 
  {text: "Hello Pluto", author: "Dunno"}, {text: "Hello Jupiter!", author: "Fiddo"},          
  {text: "Hello Uranus!", author: "Bozo"}, {text: "Hello Venus!", author: "Mom"}
];

var button = document.querySelector("button");

window.onload = function(event) {
  var next_card = document.getElementById("next_card");
  var main_card = document.getElementById("main_card");

  [next_card, main_card].forEach(function(card) {
      create_quote(card);
  });
};

function create_quote(card) {
  // style the card with quote
  card.style.backgroundColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]
  var selected_quote = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];

  var card_attrs = Array.prototype.slice.call(card.children);
  card_attrs.forEach(function(attr) {
    attr.innerText = selected_quote[attr.id.replace("_", "")];
  });
  return card;
}


function shift_quote(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var next_card = document.getElementById("next_card");
  var main_card = document.getElementById("main_card");

  main_card.style.transform = "translateY(300px)";

  var updated_main_card = next_card.cloneNode(true);
  updated_main_card.id = "main_card";
  next_card.parentElement.replaceChild(updated_main_card, main_card);

  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    create_quote(next_card);
  }
}
```

Comment: you're missing `transition` in your css
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions

Comment: After adding `transition` to get the slide down to work, I'm not sure how to reset the transition for successive click events.